# How to animate a simultaneous change in angle and rotation for a sector in manim

Tags: python, animation, manim

Is it possible to animate a rotation and a size change on the same Sector at the same time?

I know it can be cheated with `Transform` to turn it into a different Sector. But that doesn't have the animation I want. `Transform` shrinks and then expands. I want the Sector to rotate while changing size.

I can get the two effects I want but not at the same time.

I've tried but failed to find an API for `manim`. I've seen the [readthedocs](https://manim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but that isn't an API showing all the methods and variables for each Class.

```py
class Test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        rotateGroup=VGroup(*[SmallDot()],
                           Sector(angle=45*DEGREES,
                                  start_angle=25*DEGREES,
                                  stroke_width=0,
                                  fill_color=RED),
                           Sector(angle=135*DEGREES,
                                  start_angle=185*DEGREES,
                                  stroke_width=0,
                                  fill_color=GREEN))\
                                  .shift(RIGHT,DOWN)
        # Start
        self.add(rotateGroup[1])
        self.wait()
        self.play(FadeOut(rotateGroup[1]),
                  # Ideal finishing position
                  FadeIn(rotateGroup[2]))
        self.wait()
        self.remove(rotateGroup[2])
        copy1=rotateGroup[1].copy()
        copy2=rotateGroup[2].copy()
        copy3=rotateGroup[1].copy()
        self.add(copy1)
        self.wait()

        # This has the desired rotation but lacks the size change
        self.play(Rotating(copy1,
                           axis=OUT,
                           run_time=2,
                           about_point=rotateGroup[0].get_center(),
                           radians=170*DEGREES,
                           rate_func=smooth))
        self.wait()
        self.remove(copy1)

        # This has the size change but lacks the correct rotation
        self.add(copy3)
        self.play(Transform(copy3,copy2))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
class Test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        rotateGroup=VGroup(
            Sector(angle=45*DEGREES,
                    start_angle=25*DEGREES,
                    stroke_width=0,
                    fill_color=RED
            ),
            Sector(angle=135*DEGREES,
                    start_angle=185*DEGREES,
                    stroke_width=0,
                    fill_color=GREEN
                    )
        )
        red_sector, green_sector = rotateGroup
        # -----------------------------------------------
        red_sector.save_state()
        def update_sector(mob,alpha):
            mob.restore()
            angle = interpolate(45*DEGREES,135*DEGREES,alpha)
            start_angle = interpolate(25*DEGREES,185*DEGREES,alpha)
            mob.become(
                Sector(
                    angle=angle,
                    start_angle=start_angle,
                    stroke_width=0,
                    fill_color=interpolate_color(RED,GREEN,alpha)
                )
            )
        self.play(
            UpdateFromAlphaFunc(red_sector,update_sector)
        )
        self.wait()
```

As a task, try to do a custon animation, tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnWMwkcZGkM)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thank you. I'm not yet allowed to upvote